# What is the similar command of Ubuntu's sudo apt-get update in Fedora?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, software-updates

`sudo apt-get update` install all update easily in Ubuntu. Is `sudo dnf update` similar to this in Fedora 25?

Comment: Doesn't fedora use `yum` ?

Comment: @Shadur no. [Fedora is using DNF for years](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF)

Comment: @Shadur `dnf` has replaced  `yum` on the latest fedora versions

Comment: In current Fedora (F29+), `dnf` and `yum` are synonymous. Use what you like.

Answer (score 21):

As `apt-get update` (or `apt update`), a `dnf check-update` updates the local repository cache.

The (general) `dnf update` equivalent in Debian/Ubuntu is a combination of `apt update`, `apt upgrade` and `apt autoremove`.

[There is a nice comparison between the package management tools apt, yum, dnf and pkg.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/package-management-basics-apt-yum-dnf-pkg)

Answer (score 4):

`dnf` or `yum` is automatically updating the package lists when used ... for e.g. `# dnf install package`

About `dnf update` : Will update packages to the latest available version. Like `apt-get upgrade` will do.

Answer (score 3):

From `fedoraproject.org/wiki/`:

**Ubuntu command --- Fedora command**

apt-get update --- dnf check-update *You don't need to do this as dnf updates its cache automatically before performing transactions*

apt-get upgrade --- dnf upgrade

apt-get install --- dnf install

apt-get remove --- dnf remove

apt-get purge --- N/A

apt-cache search --- dnf search